# numpy.nan_to_num - 'nan' keyword not recorgnized

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When you try to replace nan value with a custom numeric value using following code,

```
np.nan_to_num(exp_allowance,nan=9999.99)
```

it produces following error:

```
typeerror: nan_to_num() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nan'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After going through several blogs and no answers to it, I discovered that I was using obsolete numpy version.This specific argument is only supported in numpy version 1.17 and above. 
Those who are facing this issue, check your numpy version:

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
```

if it is below 1.17 then update it the latest using,

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

It will work.

Comment: Hope it helps other who are facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The command to upgrade should be this:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

The --upgrade argument comes before the module name. And if you are using it for a specific Python version, the code would be:

```
python37 -m pip install --upgrade numpy
```