# Alternative for `nan_to_num()`

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I am using the following code on a high computation cluster:

```
array = np.nan_to_num(
     array,
     copy = False,
     # Replace
     nan = 0.0,
     posinf = 0.0,
     neginf = 0.0
)
```

The code causes the following error:

```
Module for Anaconda3 2019.03 loaded.
Run script ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 118, in <module>
    neginf = 0.0
TypeError: nan_to_num() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nan'
Done
```

I googled the error. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689390/5696601), my code can only be run by `NumPy > v1.17`. The high computation cluster environment uses `NumPy v1.16.2` and `Python v3.7.3`.

What code snippet can replace my code snippet above?

Answer (score 2):

You can revert [`np.isfinite`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html#numpy.isfinite) to get non-finite values and modify them by indexing:

```
array[~np.isfinite(array)] = 0.0
```

little explanation:

```
array = np.array([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf, 3])

np.isfinite(array)
# [False False False  True]

~np.isfinite(array)
# [ True  True  True False]

array[~np.isfinite(array)] = 0.0
# [0. 0. 0. 3.]
```

If the performance be of importance, [`~np.isfinite` can be accelerated with numba accelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932228/13394817) in parallel no-python mode, which will be more faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use the property that `Nan!=Nan`

```
array[array!=array] = nan_value
```

And compare with `np.inf` for infinite values:

```
array[array==np.inf] = pos_inf_value
array[array==(-np.inf)] = neg_inf_value
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I went for `array[np.isposinf(array)] = 0` and `array[np.isnan(array)] = 0`.

Comment: @Stücke why doing this explicitly, not using `np.isfinite` as my answer?  `np.isfinite` will be much faster than the used one (as you are mentioning), at least 5 times faster on huge data volumes I have tested.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'll check that and adapt your code snippet!

Comment: @Stücke If the performance is of importance, I have proposed [another similar solution using numba accelerator which makes this more faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932228/13394817).